# Write function that accepts two argument types but does the same thing

Tags: generics, rust

Here's my `src/main.rs` file:

```rust
use chrono_tz::Tz;
use chrono::FixedOffset;
use chrono::{NaiveDateTime, TimeZone, NaiveDate};


fn my_func(from_tz: Tz, ndt: NaiveDateTime){
    let res = from_tz.from_local_datetime(&ndt);
    println!("res: {:?}", res);
}

fn main() {
    let area_location: Tz = "UTC".parse().unwrap();
    let hour = 3600;
    let fixed_offset: FixedOffset = FixedOffset::east_opt(5 * hour).unwrap();
    let ndt = NaiveDate::from_ymd_opt(2038, 1, 19).unwrap().and_hms_opt(3, 14, 08).unwrap();
    my_func(area_location, ndt)
}
```

and `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "tmp"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
chrono = "0.4.23"
chrono-tz = "0.8.1"
regex = "1.7.1"
```

The code runs fine and prints

```
res: Single(2038-01-19T03:14:08UTC)
```

However, I can also change the last line of `main` to `my_func(fixed_offset, ndt)`, and change the type of `from_tz` in `my_func` to `FixedOffset`, and the code will still run just fine, printing

```
res: Single(2038-01-19T03:14:08+05:00)
```

In my application, I don't know whether I'll receive a `Tz` or a `FixedOffset`. Either way, I'd like to pass it to `my_func`, and inside it do `from_tz.from_local_datetime(&ndt)`.

How can I let `my_func` accept either `Tz` or `FixedOffset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the method in question is of the trait [`TimeZone`](https://docs.rs/chrono/0.4.23/chrono/offset/trait.TimeZone.html) so you can just accept a generic argument bound to that trait:

```rust
fn my_func<T: TimeZone>(from_tz: T, ndt: NaiveDateTime){
    let res = from_tz.from_local_datetime(&ndt);
    println!("res: {:?}", res);
}
```